# What determines the .Net version used for Garbage Collection?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

In .Net 4 there is improved Garbage Collection which is important for our systems.

If I have a .Net 4 Winforms project that references .Net 2/.Net3.5 class libraries what version of .Net is used for Garbage Collection?

I am keen to get the .Net 4 GC working and so if the project files (*.csproj) files have to be changed to use .Net 4 for the .Net 4 GC to kick in, so be it.

Thanks

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that you'll notice any improvement in a winforms project.  Docs for the new background collection, replacing concurrent collection, are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx#background_garbage_collection

Comment: I agree but my winforms project consumes various assemblies which use multiple threads and dictionary lookups as well as other real time critical processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GC used will be the CLR running. If you are using .net 4 CLR for your executable then the 2.0 objects will run in the 4.0 CLR, unless they run out of process.

If you have an .exe that is built for CLR2 then it will still use CLR2 by default. To force a .net 2.0 CLR exe to run on the CLR 4.0 use the following in the config file.

```
<configuration>

  <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>

  </startup>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Just to confirm.  If my *.exe is using v4 then the v2 references will run in the v4 CLR and therefore take advantage of the better Garbage Collection

Comment: In the app.config of the older assemblies?

Comment: I've edited the question, but yes the executable will be CLR 4.

Comment: What do you mean by "run out of process"?

Comment: if the other other objects are hosted in a remote process (e.g .net remoting and you linking only the communication proxies)

Comment: Would a remote process include seperate threads? eg/The .Net 2 assembly creates a thread to do some processing on

Comment: @Jon: A remote thread implies at least one other thread, but the inverse is not true. The mere existance of another thread does not imply the existance of another process. And in the case of your example, the helper thread certainly exists in the same process.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into remote process on Google and think I understand it!